# Using Azure Feature Disabled controller won't turn on after change to true

Tags: azure, azure-feature-manager

I'm trying to use the Azure Feature flag feature to enable or disable an entire controller with

`[FeatureGate("feature-key"]`

If I set this to true in Azure Portal and it works the call to the API endpoint returns 200.

If switch on the Azure portal to false then until I restart the application it won't disable it.

But if I use the IFeature interface, the value is correctly taken from the azure configuration

```
 var x = await _featureManager.IsEnabledAsync("sync-OTA-real-time");
```

This shows the correct value set in the Azure Portal.

Is the controller's habilitation loaded only one time?

Thanks